# Cannot autowire ClientRepository and FineractServiceOpenFeign

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, feign

I am trying to autowire FineractServiceOpenFeign and ClientRepository but it's not getting autowired and throwing null pointer exception.Can someone please help in checking? I tried using @ComponentScan due to several modules and packages but it's still not working.

```
package org.mifos.chatbot.server.service.Impl;


import org.mifos.chatbot.server.repository.ClientRepository;
import org.mifos.chatbot.server.service.FineractService;
import org.mifos.chatbot.server.config.openFeign.FineractServiceOpenFeign;
import org.mifos.chatbot.server.model.Client;
import org.mifos.chatbot.server.model.Tracker;
import org.mifos.chatbot.server.request.PostAuthenticationRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class FineractServiceImpl implements FineractService {

   @Autowired
   private ClientRepository clientRepository;
   @Autowired
   private FineractServiceOpenFeign openFeign;

    @Override
    public void authorization(String text) {
        String[] splitString = text.split("\\:");

        if (splitString.length >= 2) {
            String adminUsername = splitString[1];
            String adminPassword = splitString[2];
            String clientUsername = splitString[3];

            // TODO add logging
            PostAuthenticationRequest request = PostAuthenticationRequest.builder()
                    .username(adminUsername)
                    .password(adminPassword)
                    .build();
            // TODO check if tenantIdentifier will always be default
//            ResponseEntity feignResponse = openFeign.authenticate
//                    (request, "default");
            // TODO verify the client exists
            //if(feignResponse.getStatusCode().value() == 200) {
            if(true) {
                Client client = Client.builder()
                        .adminUsername(adminUsername)
                        .adminPassword(adminPassword)
                        .clientUsername(clientUsername)
                        .build();
                clientRepository.save(client);
                // TODO any values that need to be saved in db? What are next steps?
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getLoanStatus(Tracker tracker) {
        // 1. find list of loans
        ResponseEntity feignResponse = openFeign.getLoan(226, "default");
        if(feignResponse.getStatusCode().value() == 200) {

        }
        else {

        }

        // 2. if only one item then return the loan status and call loan/{id} api
        // 3. if multiple items then ask the loan id
        // 4. call loan/{id} api
    }
}
```

```
package org.mifos.chatbot.server;

import org.mifos.chatbot.server.config.openFeign.FineractServiceOpenFeign;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@EnableSwagger2
@EnableFeignClients({"org.mifos"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "org.mifos")
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "org.mifos.chatbot.server.service",
        "org.mifos.chatbot.server.repository",
        "org.mifos.chatbot.server"})
@ImportAutoConfiguration({FeignAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ChatbotApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ChatbotApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
package org.mifos.chatbot.server.repository;

import org.mifos.chatbot.server.model.Client;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@EnableMongoRepositories
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends MongoRepository<Client, String> {

}
```

```
package org.mifos.chatbot.server.config.openFeign;

import org.mifos.chatbot.server.request.PostAuthenticationRequest;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@FeignClient(name="fineract-provider", url = "https://localhost:8080/fineract-provider/api")
@Component
public interface FineractServiceOpenFeign {
    @PostMapping(value = "/v1/authentication", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> authenticate(@RequestBody PostAuthenticationRequest request, @RequestParam String tenantIdentifier);

    @GetMapping(value = "v1/self/loans/{loanId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getLoan(@PathVariable Integer loanId, @RequestParam String tenantIdentifier);
}
```

This is the structure of my server module that has all the above files
[image]